# repeat do while loop if switch statement reaches default

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

I have a do while loop asking for user input. Inside this do while loop I have a switch statement. How can I make it so that if the default value is met repeat the loop asking for the users gender again?

```
do
    {
        cout << "What is your weight?" << endl;
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "What is your height?" << endl;
        cin >> height;
        cout << "What is your age?" << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << "What is your gender?" << endl;
        cin >> gender;

        switch (gender)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                cout << endl << Male(weight, height, age);
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                cout << endl << Female(weight, height, age);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "What is your gender?";
        }

        cout << "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> stopApp;

    } while(toupper(stopApp) == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 5):

One option is to set up a boolean value and if the default case is reached set it to true to repeat.

```
bool repeat;
do {
  repeat = false;
  //switch statement
  switch {
    default:
      repeat = true;
  }
while(repeat);
```

You could appropriately use repeat to know which question you would like to repeat as well.

Answer (score 4):

A typical pattern for this kind of thing is to loop until the user enters valid input. IE

```
    do {
        cout << "What is your weight?" << endl;
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "What is your height?" << endl;
        cin >> height;
        cout << "What is your age?" << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << "What is your gender?" << endl;
        cin >> gender;
    } while (!validGender(gender));

    // process valid input
```

While this doesn't precisely answer your question, it is a good pattern for what you're trying to do.

Comment: how would you make it so you only ask for gender again not each question?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the overloading of `break` to mean both "end of switch case" and "exit loop", this is one of those unusual times where `goto` is appropriate.

```
do
    {
    again:
        cout << "What is your weight?" << endl;
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "What is your height?" << endl;
        cin >> height;
        cout << "What is your age?" << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << "What is your gender?" << endl;
        cin >> gender;

        switch (gender)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                cout << endl << Male(weight, height, age);
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                cout << endl << Female(weight, height, age);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "What is your gender?";
                goto again;
        }

        cout << "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> stopApp;

    } while(toupper(stopApp) == 'Y');
```

FYI "male" and "female" are [not the only options for gender](https://www.genderspectrum.org/understanding-gender).  Depending on your larger goals, I would recommend that you either avoid asking this question at all, allow the user to provide an arbitrary phrase in response, or, if this is a medical application where *biological sex* is the actual relevant piece of information, ask for that instead (and again allow provision of an arbitrary phrase, because *that's* not binary either).

Answer (score 1):

```
do
{
    cout << "What is your weight?" << endl;
    cin >> weight;
    cout << "What is your height?" << endl;
    cin >> height;
    cout << "What is your age?" << endl;
    cin >> age;

    bool repeat(true);
    do {
        cout << "What is your gender?" << endl;
        cin >> gender;

        switch (gender)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                cout << endl << Male(weight, height, age);
                repeat = false;
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                cout << endl << Female(weight, height, age);
                repeat = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } while(repeat)

    cout << "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> stopApp;

} while(toupper(stopApp) == 'Y');
```